# UiAutomator 2.0 test from command line

Tags: android, junit, instrumentation, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to use Android UIAutomator for some simple tests, I'm aware of that it needs to be built by Gradle since UIAutomator 2.0, I can run my simple test which only presses home button via Android Studio or command line by "gradlew.bat cC", I was wondering how I can run it with adb command?

I tried

```
adb shell am instrument -w test.simple.uiatest/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

as suggested [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html#RunTestsDevice) , but I get

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{test.simple.uiatest/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: test.simple.uiatest/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:951)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:316)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:99)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:250)
```

Below are my code snippet and build.gradle, what am I doing wrong?

```
package test.simple.uiatest;

import android.support.test.uiautomator.UiDevice;
import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;

public class ApplicationTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {
    private UiDevice theDevice;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        theDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());

        theDevice.pressHome();
    }

    public void testName() throws Exception {
        theDevice.pressHome();
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"

    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        applicationId "test.simple.uiatest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you're seeing will occur if the test APK is not installed, or if the <test_package>/<runner_class> in your `am instrument ...` command is wrong.

To list the instrumentation tests that are available on your device, you can run `adb shell pm list instrumentation`. You should see a line like:

```
instrumentation:test.simple.uiatest/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner (target=simple.target.app)
```

If you don't see a line matching your test, then you need to install the test APK. If it is installed, double check that the `test.simple.uiatest/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner` portion of the `pm list instrumentation` output matches your `am instrument` command.

Answer (score 1):

As the build.gradle in your post, you should use "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

```
adb shell am instrument  -w test.simple.uiatest/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Answer (score 1):

for your package, try this：

```
adb shell am instrument -w test.simple.uiatest.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

use package `test.simple.uiatest.test` instead.